# Error when using offset in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using offset function in VBA. But, for example, when I'm in the first row, `offset(-5,0)` returns an error message. Of course, I can't offset -5 rows when I'm in first row.

How can I check it?

I tried using `if rangeEx = range("A1")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? I'm guessing you probably have something like `rangeEx.Offset` rather that just `offset(-5,0)` as you have written in your question... If you provide that bit more, we could help...

Comment: try `If rangeEx.Column>5 Then rangeEx.Offset(-5,0).Value="test"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, misstype:) `If rangeEx.Row>5 Then ..`

Comment: I use rangeEX.column to check, and it work. Thank you. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `.Row` property of the cell and see if it's less than or equal to 5.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim RangeEx As Range
    Set RangeEx = ActiveCell

    If RangeEx.Row <= 5 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Offset at " & RangeEx.Offset(-5, 0).Address
    End If

End Sub
```

Result on rows 1-5:

[image]

Result on row 6++:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This example uses **Selection**

```
Sub RangeCheck()
If ActiveCell.Row < 6 Then
    MsgBox ".OFFSET(-5,0) will fail"
End If
End Sub
```